# Reading text files by line and storing character values in a cell string? (MATLAB)

Tags: string, matlab, file, file-io, cell-array

I have a function that I use for single strings. However, I want to extend this to many text files.

My text files are of the form of:

*first line of garbage*

*continuous text with no spaces*

*continuous text with no spaces*

*continuous text with no spaces*

*continuous text with no spaces*

There are no blank spaces between the lines (Stack Overflow requires a double space for a new line). I would like to read each line of continuous text and store it in the element of a cell of strings. How could I do this?

EDIT: I know I would have to do something along the lines of:

```
file1 = fopen(link','rb');
while file ~EOF
grab every text value by line, call it data
file1 = fopen(file1, data)
store in cell array
```

Comment: See this answer in Matlab Central: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/317699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html):

```
C = importdata('file.txt'); %// import each line into a cell
C = C(2:end); %// remove first cell (header)
```

Comment: Much quicker! Thank you!